# leer desde la primera hoja de un excel

Tags: php, excel

Estoy realizando un proyecto que saca los datos de un excel con varias pestañas *(pestaña por año)* y me lo implementa en la tabla, pero resulta que cuando lo mando leer del excel solo me lee la ultima hoja, no se cómo hacerle para que lea todas.

Este es el código PHP completo:

```
<?php

class Conversion {

    private $_objPHPExcel;
    private $_sheet;
    private $_rows;
    private $_accountingCodes;
    private $_accountingEntries;

    public function __construct($file_type, $local_file){

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
        //lista de folios del archivo excel
        $worksheetList = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($local_file);
        $lastSheet = count($worksheetList) - 1;
        $this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$lastSheet];

        $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($this->_sheet);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $this->_objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($local_file);

    }

    public function filterAccountingCodes() {

        $highestRow = $this->_objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

        $codes = $this->_objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:' . 'A' . $highestRow, 0, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE);

        foreach ($codes as $row => $column) {

            if (substr($column['A'], 0, 10) != '          ') {
                unset($codes[$row]);
            }else{
                $column_filtered[] = explode('    ' , substr($column['A'],10));
                $this->_accountingCodes = $column_filtered;
            }
        }

        $this->_rows = array_keys($codes);

    }


    public function filterAccountingEntries(){

        /*Construye array de entradas contables a partir de un rango de celdas*/

        foreach ( $this->_rows as $rows => $row ) {
            $accounts[] = $this->_objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('C' . $row . ':N' .$row, 0, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
        }

        foreach($accounts as $key => $value) {
            $accounts_filtered[] = $value[0];
        }

        /*Filtrado del array de códigos eliminando concepto*/

        foreach ($this->_accountingCodes as $key => $value) {
            $codes_filtered[] = $value[0]; 
        }

        /*Unificación de ambos arrays incluyendo fecha de cada entrada contable*/

        $arrayLenght = count($codes_filtered);

        for ($i = 0 ; $i < $arrayLenght ; $i++){

            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 12 ; $j++){

                $year = '20'.substr($this->_sheet, -2);
                $monthNum = $j + 1;
                $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
                $month = $dateObj->format('m'); 

                $account[] = $codes_filtered[$i] .  ' ' . $year .'-' . $month . '-01' . ' ' . $accounts_filtered[$i][$j];
            }
        }


        foreach ($account as $row) {

            $accounting_entries[] = explode(' ' , $row);

        }

        $this->_accountingEntries = $accounting_entries;

    }

    public function accountingCodesCSV($file){

        $csv = fopen($file, 'w');

        foreach ($this->_accountingCodes as $fields) {
            fputcsv($csv, $fields, $delimiter = "\t", $enclosure = '"');
        }

        fclose($csv);
    }

    public function accountingEntriesCSV($file){

        $csv = fopen($file, 'w');

        foreach ($this->_accountingEntries as $fields) {
            fputcsv($csv, $fields, $delimiter = "\t", $enclosure = '"');
        }

        fclose($csv);
    }  

}

?>
```

Comment: Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Por curiosidad, ¿este código lo has tomado de alguna página? En esta línea `$this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$lastSheet];` me parece a mi que efectivamente le estás enviando la última hoja, de pronto con `$lastSheet` puedes hacer un loop y llamar a la hoja así: `$this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$incremento_hoja];`.

Comment: se ha realizado entre varias personas, es un proyecto de final de curso, pero hemos ido cogiendo el codigo desde la documentacion de la libreria phpexcel y tb cosas desde internet. Perdona pero no me termino de aclarar con lo que me dices,disculpa

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTA**: *Esto es solo un pseudo-código que no garantiza el funcionamiento
>   del programa*.

Como te mencionaba en el comentario, en tu código tienes esta línea que le dice al método que lee el excel solo la última hoja:

```
$this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$lastSheet];
```

Mi sugerencia es que cambies el código para que realices un ciclo y recorras las hojas del excel:

```
public function __construct($file_type, $local_file){

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

        // lista de folios del archivo excel.
        $worksheetList = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($local_file);

        // Aquí miras cuántas hojas tiene tu archivo Excel.
        $cantidadHojas = count($worksheetList);

        // Aquí deberías haces un ciclo para que (por cada ciclo)
        // llame al evento que procesa la hoja excel.
        for ($hojaExcel = 0; $hojaExcel <= $cantidadHojas; $hojaExcel++) {

            // Aquí le estoy pasando el valor de "$hojaExcel".
            $this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$hojaExcel];    
            $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($this->_sheet);
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $this->_objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($local_file);
        }

    }
```

Comment: el codigo va bien pero no me actualiza la tabla las pestañas anteriores a la ultima, me da error dice   $this->_sheet = $worksheetList[$hojaExcel]; no existe,dice Undefined offset:

Comment: @racxo revisa bien todo: ¿el archivo excel tiene las mismas hojas detectadas por el código fuente?, ¿cada hoja tiene la información que necesitas?. Empieza mirando si el valor de `$hojaExcel ` es la cantidad de hojas reales del archivo de Excel.

Comment: me las cuenta mal, ya que le he echo un eco y me dice que hay 19 pestañas y solo tengo 7